# Access instance of MatMenuTrigger component in Angular test

Tags: angular, testing, angular-material, angular6, angular-test

I'm trying to create a test for Angular component that contains MatMenu from Angular Material in its template. I want to test items inside that menu. It turns out that HTML inside MatMenu is compiled only after opening the menu so I need to invoke an openMenu method on menu trigger somehow. The problem is I cannot find a way to get a reference to MatMenuTrigger component in Angular test. For most of the components when I query them using for e.g. `debugElement.queryAllNodes(By.directive(MatIcon))` I get a DebugElement with a componentInstance property which is exactly what I need, but unfortunately for MatMenuTrigger it doesn't work that way. I don't know why but this code `debugElement.queryAllNodes(By.directive(MatMenuTrigger))[0].componentInstance`  is returning parent component instance (same as `debugElement.componentInstance`), not the MatMenuTrigger that I can use to open menu.

Is this a bug in Angular testing framework or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show all of your test code - especially the test component template. Also show the component code.

Comment: If this was ever resolved I'd love to know how, having the same issue

Comment: @LucasSenCabAUgh Unfortunately I wasn't able to resolve it, I refactored the code to workaround this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can spy on `MatMenuTrigger` functions like `closeMenu` getting the instance of `MatMenuTrigger` from the button (element) that triggers the menu.

```js
it('calls Close Menu on Cancel', () => {
  const menuTigger: MatMenuTrigger = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatMenuTrigger)).injector.get(MatMenuTrigger);
  spyOn(menuTigger, 'closeMenu');
  component.onCancel();
  expect(menuTigger.closeMenu).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  templateUrl: './my-parent.component.html'
})
export class MyParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('myMenuTrigger')
  private readonly menuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  public onCancel(): void {
    this.menuTrigger.closeMenu();
  }
}
```

```html
<button mat-button #myMenuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" [matMenuTriggerFor]="dateMenu">
  My Menu
</button>
<mat-menu #myMenu="matMenu">
   <!-- -->
</mat-menu>
```